# SQL/PHP: Joins with no matches on the other table (multiple tables)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, outer-join

I have four tables:

```
Personal_trainer(personaltrainerID, name, age, location)
Client(clientID, name, age, location)
Nutrition_Plan(NutritionplanID, personaltrainerID, clientID)
Training_Plan(TrainingplanID, personaltrainerID, clientID)
```

I'm trying to display that when a personal trainer creates a nutrition/training plan and assigns it to a client, only their specific clients appear as a result, but their is no foreign key in the client table to identify the coach (due to the criteria of the project)

I'm wondering what is the SQL for the neccessary join on both the training/nutrition plan. I have been trying for quite some time and here is my sample code.

Desired output is all the client data IF ONLY they have been assigned either a training or nutrition plan by that specific trainer

In the statement I'm having issues with the Bind parameter so that only users with clients can see their clients. If i use a specified ID i can get a return!

```
    <?php 
            //code to search for a item from the database
            // user can enter any character to search for a value from the db
           if (isset($_POST['search']))
           {
               $valueToSearch = $_POST['ValueToSearch'];
               $query = "select * from client WHERE concat(`clientID`, `name`, `age`, `sex`, `weight`, `height`, `yearsExperience`, `goal`, `injuries`, 'email')like'%".$valueToSearch."%'";
               $search_result = filterTable($query);

           }
           else {
           $query = "select *
            from client
            where clientID in (select clientID from nutrition_plan where personaltrainerID=?)
            or clientID in (select clientID from training_plan where personalTrainerID=?)";
           $query->bind_param("i", $_POST[""]);
               $search_result = filterTable($query);
           }
           //code to filter the db
           function filterTable($query)
           {
               $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost:3308","root","","fypdatabase");
               $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
               return $filter_Result;
           }
           ?>

           <?php
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result))
          { //display the details from the db in the table with option to delete or update entry 
            ?>
                    <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row["clientID"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["age"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["sex"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["weight"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["height"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["yearsExperience"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["goal"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["injuries"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["email"]; ?></td>
                    <td> 
                        <a href="?Delete=<?php echo $row["clientID"]; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="updateClient.php?Edit=<?php echo $row["clientID"]; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">Update</a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php
```

Comment: "IF ONLY they have been assigned a training/nutrition plan" AND or OR?

Comment: You might want a simple `INNER JOIN` chain with the `USING(xxxID)` clause. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: OR! sorry ill make the change!

Comment: you have an error in your query `SELECT * FROM` then `LEFT JOIN` with full criteria and after filter using `WHERE`

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone thank you! how would i write that?

Comment: Then you need a `DISTINCT personaltrainerID, clientID` in a `UNION` query. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

Comment: So far this query is almost there I just need to change what the "id" is equal too at the end:

'"SELECT * from client JOIN nutrition_plan ON client.clientID=nutrition_plan.clientID JOIN personal_trainer ON personal_trainer.personalTrainerID=nutrition_plan.personaltrainerID Where personal_trainer.personalTrainerID='id'";'

Comment: If you have got a working solution so far and have additional questions like bind parameters of your HTML form, you should accept an answer and open a new specific question with the HTML and PHP snippet. StackOverflow (SO) is meant to answer one specific problem per question.

Comment: Great i will open a new question thanks so much for your help all ive to do is fix the bind param!! Much appreciated thank you :)

Comment: Great i will open a new question thanks so much for your help all ive to do is fix the bind param!! Much appreciated thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name, age, location FROM Client
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT personaltrainerID, clientID from Nutrion_Plan 
  UNION DISTINCT 
  SELECT personaltrainerID, clientID from Training_Plan
) u
USING(clientID)
WHERE u.personaltrainerID = ?;
```

Comment: Thank you thats great!! What would you replace "1" instead of so that different personaltrainerID's can be used when different trainers log in?

Comment: Of course a parameter like `?` for a prepared statement.

Comment: When i include a ? mark on its own no results are returned, should there be another line for binding a parameter? See my edited example above please!

Comment: Since you have tagged your question to belong to PHP, I expect you want to use mysqli's or DBO's `prepare` method. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php / http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php That's highly recommended since interpolating client data directly into SQL would make your app vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I'm using bind param but after the "i" for integer i dont know what value to pass into it?

$query->bind_param("i", $_POST[""]); ----> not sure whats meant to be where post is

Comment: @Darán You can use a named parameter like `:trainerid` as well.

Comment: That's whatever your form `<input name="someName">` is. It is reflected in the `$_POST` array, provided that the form method is post, otherwise `$_GET`.

Comment: Probably it is not posted via form but taken from the `$_SESSION` if there is a trainer login. If not, there might be a dropdown field showing names as captions and sending the selected ID. Then you might find a `<select>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I understand your request correctly ...

Show only clients that have a nutrition or training plan by trainer 123:

```
select *
from client
where clientid in (select clientid from nutrition_plan where personaltrainerid = 123)
   or clientid in (select clientid from training_plan where personaltrainerid = 123);
```

Show these clients along with all their plans (regardless of the plans' trainers):

```
select *
from client
join
(
  select 'nutrition' as kind, nutritionplanid as id, personaltrainerid, clientid
  from nutrition_plan
  union all
  select 'training' as kind, trainingplanid as id, personaltrainerid, clientid
  from training_plan
) plan using (clientid)
where clientid in (select clientid from nutrition_plan where personaltrainerid = 123)
   or clientid in (select clientid from training_plan where personaltrainerid = 123);
```

Comment: That looks good thank you! when the pesonaltrainerID is coming from the database and could be any number, what would it be instead of '123' for instance? Would it be '?'

Comment: It's coming from the database? What does it mean? From another table, e.g. `select personaltrainerid from personal_trainer where name = 'John Smith'`? Then you can simply replace 123 with this subquery in parantheses: `... where personaltrainerid = (select personaltrainerid from personal_trainer where name = 'John Smith'));`

Comment: Great thank you! so i should take your second example that should work?

Comment: If this is what you want. Try it and check the results. The query gets you all clients with all their plans, provided at least one of the client's plans is by the desired trainer.

Comment: I get you thank you, I tried the first query and no errors were present but the output of the client wasnt displayed in the table!

Comment: Make sure you use a trainer ID of a trainer that actually does have a plan in nutrition_plan or training_plan.

Comment: It worked for that specific ID! However I want to make it so that any trainer from the table sees their own clients when they log in with their id? for example, id 4, 6, 8 would see only their clients
should i use '?' for that? Another words, any personalTrainerId in training/nutrition plans

Comment: Yes, mysqli uses the `?` for bind parameters. Here is the related docs: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Ive updated the above question with bind parameter but I am unsure what to write in it after the "i" for integer?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

`SELECT * from client JOIN nutrition_plan ON client.clientid=nutritionplan.clientid JOIN Personaltrainer ON Personaltrainer.personaltrainerID=nutritionplan.personaltrainerID Where Personaltrainer.personaltrainerID="id"`

Comment: Thanks Kashan its almost there! However what is the "id" at the end relating too? thats where my error is, personaltrainerID?

Comment: this should actually display that through his personal id or name

Comment: I get you, it doesnt throw any errors and runs, however no data is displayed in the table!

Comment: @Darán: This query gives you one personal trainer, their nutrition plans and the related clients. If you take the query as is, i.e. with `"id"` literally then you would look up trainer ID 0, because `"id"` means a column named `id`, and as this doesn't exist, MySQL defaults to a string `'id'` instead, and as this isn't a number, it gets converted to `0`.